# How can I convert STRING to CHAR in an ABAP CDS view?

Tags: cds

I have a STRING field (standard /AIF/ALERTS-KEYFIELDSTRING), but I need it as CHAR in an ABAP CDS view (no table function) for further functions. I am aware it will cut off anything after a set number of characters, but I am fine with that.

Neither of these work:

```
cast(KEYFIELDSTRING as abap.char(100)) as c_keyfieldstring
  
substring(KEYFIELDSTRING, 1, 100) as c_keyfieldstring
```

Comment: It depends a lot on the ABAP version you are using.

Comment: @SandraRossi, I am interested in any versions, but this is not something to be solved in ABAP.

Comment: ABAP CDS depends on ABAP version. There are lots of changes in each ABAP version. A solution would fit one version but not another one.

Comment: @SandraRossi, virtual elements are not good, I need to keep the results on the DB. Other than that, the older the better, it should go into the standard

Comment: What type is KEYFIELDSTRING? Is it not char already - how did you declare this?

Comment: @Bernard, it is a string. I have not declared it, it is in a standard table.

Comment: @András tested this - only get a success (not sure what error you are getting?) - see below on my workings

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Sting (CLOB) are not supported in CDS. You cannot do casting , left, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely works:

```
define view Z02_CAST  
as select from Z02_CUSTOMER as c
{  
   cast(c.name as abap.char(4))        as c_keyfieldstring
}
```

[image]

Need to see the table field definition perhaps.
What error are you getting. Maybe its working but 100 characters is too long to show up easily?